# Proof that $x^2-y^3=1$ has only one solution in the domain of $N^+$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

How can I prove that $x^2-y^3=1$ has only one solution in the domain of $N^+$?
Namely $x=3, y=2$.
My try:
$x^2-1=y^3  => (x-1)(x+1)-1=y^3$.
$gcd(x-1,x+1)$ is 2 if $x$ is odd and $1$ if $x$ is even.
 In the case x-even the only possible solution would be if $x=1$ but $y>0$. Therefore $x$ is odd.
 Let $x=2p+1$. We can rewrite the equation as $4p(p+1)=y^3$.
 $gcd(p,p+1)=1$, therefore $p(p+1)=2$. Therefore $x=3$.
 Is that correct ?

Comment: Rewrite it as $x^2 - 1 = y^3$. Note that $x^2 - 1 = (x+1)(x-1)$. Continue from there.

Comment: $gcd(x-1,x+1)$ is 2 if $x$ is odd and $1$ if $x$ is even. In the case x-even the only possible solution would be if $x=1$ but $y>0$. Therefore $x$ is odd. Let $x=2p+1$. We can rewrite it as $4p(p+1)=y^3$. $gcd(p,p+1)=0$ therefore $p(p+1)=2$.Therefore $x=3$ Is that orrect ?

Comment: I'm stuck in the case when $x$ is odd.

Comment: I made a mistake $gcd(p,p+1)=1.$

Comment: This is a Mordell's equation with a simple but slightly long solution. See pages 7-8 of this paper: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/mordelleqn1.pdf

Comment: You can find several arguments at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/39561/ which one suits your needs depends a bit on your background.